# Сверточная нейронная сеть

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow

Хочу создать нейронную сеть для бинарной классификации стрелок на картинках  дорожных путей. Подскажите пожалуйста какая архитектура подойдет больше всего.
Пока написаны вот такие слои... но результат низкий(60%)

```
def get_model():
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(50,80,1)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.75))

model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.75))

model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
return model

model = get_model()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer= 'rmsprop',
          metrics=['acc'])
```

Comment: Можете пояснить что вы понимаете под "бинарной классификацией стрелок на картинках дорожных путей"? Бинарная классификация - это когда в качестве результата вы ожидаете получить одно из двух возможных значений (обычно это "да" или "нет") для каждой картинки. Вы хотите определить присутствует ли какая-либо стрелка на картинке?

Comment: да, хочу определять если на данной картинке стрелка или же нет ее.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько вещей, которые сразу бросаются в глаза:

1. если вы используете функцию активации `softmax`, то в качестве функции ошибки надо использовать `categorical_crossentropy`. Обычно в случае бинарной классификации на выходном слое только один нейрон со значениями `1` или `0` и в этом случае используют функцию активации `sigmoid` в комбинации с функцией потери `binary_crossentropy`:

   ```
   ...
   model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))    # output layer
   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', ...)
   ```
2. По-моему у вас слишком большой коэффициент регуляризации в `Dropout` слоях. Стоит начать с меньшего (например с `0.2`) и настраивать его...

PS советую начать изучение с того, чтобы скопировать хорошо зарекомендовавшие себя архитектуры сетей и "поиграться" с ними. В качестве примера можно взять [VGG16](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-VGG-neural-network)

Comment: а если график функции потер не сходиться? то уменьшать Dropout?